# JavaScript: why .forEach doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined

Here is a little piece of code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
        console.log('loaded entity=' + entity)
    })
})

console.log(['echo'])
console.log(['echo'].forEach)
['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
    console.log('entity=' + entity)
})
```

Output looks like this:

```
["echo"]
function forEach() { [native code] }
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'echo' of undefined
loaded entity=echo
```

Why does this error occur? I assume that `undefined` is `this` inside `.forEach`. Why doesn't it get passed when calling `.forEach`?

Comment: Same error in all browsers??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***SEMICOLONS!***

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
        console.log('loaded entity=' + entity);
    })
});

console.log(['echo']);
console.log(['echo'].forEach);
['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
    console.log('entity=' + entity);
});
```

---

The problem is here:

```
console.log(['echo'].forEach)
['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
```

The line break is ignored, at it gets parsed as this:

```
console.log(['echo'].forEach)['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
```

`console.log()` returns `undefined`, and `undefined['echo']` raises an exception.

So use semicolons and be happy. Or don't and suffer.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  JavaScript will continue to parse if there is no semicolons.  Don't rely on the automatic adding of them.

Comment: This is the very first time I suffered from not adding semicolons. And this is a serious issue. Thank you.

Comment: I'd love to hear from those who are promoting not using semicolons in JS, what would they say now. Thanks to that stupid idea new JS devs see code without semicolons, don't use them and then this happens. Of course, there are rules to follow when not using semicolons which prevent from such issues, but first one have to learn them. And usually we learn too late.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to add semi-colons](http://benalman.com/news/2012/04/semicolons-required-in-javascript/). Your script is being evaluated as:

```
console.log(['echo'].forEach)['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
    console.log('entity=' + entity)
})
```

And since `console.log` returns `undefined`, you get an uncaught TypeError because you can't access an `echo` property on `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can work without semicolons (treating newlines as end of statement), as long as concatenation of following lines is syntactically incorrect & parsing makes no sense.

For eg:

```
var a=1
var b=2
```

would work since the semicolon will be added as `var a=1 var b=2` doesn't make sense.

Thus it will be treated as `var a=1; var b=2`. Similarly,

```
console.log(['echo'].forEach)
['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
    console.log('entity=' + entity)
})
```

is read as :

```
console.log(['echo'].forEach)['echo'].forEach(function(entity) {
    console.log('entity=' + entity)
})
```

Here `console.log(...)` is treated an object with the property `'echo'`. Hence the error.